# tensorflow C API static library

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, static-libraries, tensorflow-c++

Can I build/get static library (.a files instead of .so files) of [tensorflow C API](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c)? I need to include/link tensorflow c api in my C++ software xyz and then I build shared library xyz.so that will be sent to other party. The other party should be able to run xyz.so without installing/building tensorflow.

Comment: `Can I build` what have you tried? What research did you do? What did it resulted it? Did you even see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28388 ? `other party should be able to run xyz.so without installing/building tensorflow` Why do you need a static library for that? Typically I see `LD_PRELOAD` used. You are asking XY question, no?

Answer (score 0):

Download tensorflow c api and link .so files using CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten some things to work by compiling Tensorflow with the following bazel command:

```
bazel build --config=monolithic -j 1 //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
```

And then linking together the object files with `libtool` for MacOS:

```
libtool -static -o libtensorflow_arm64_libtool_SO3.a $(cat bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so.*.params | sed -e 's!-Wl,-force_load,!!' | grep -e '\.a$' -e '\.lo$' | sort -t: -u -k1,1)
```

Or `ar` for linux:

```
ar -cr libtensorflow.a $(cat bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so.*.params | grep '\.o$')
```

I have not figured out all the details, but this does make at least version control and tensor allocation work.

EDIT:

In the end I opted for going with TFLite as it supports almost all TF operations and have `Cmake` support for building static libraries. For the full solution see this thread:
[Has anyone experience in building a static library for the Tensorflow C++ API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74462352/has-anyone-experience-in-building-a-static-library-for-the-tensorflow-c-api/74557906#74557906)